# ¿Cómo hacer muchas regresiones en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una base en excel de esta forma : [image]

Necesito hacer una regresión múltiple entre rindess como variable dependiente y dic,ene,feb como regresores para cada uno de los departamentos. Es decir, una regresión para 25 de Mayo, 9 de Julio ...

Mi código es el siguiente.

```
library(readxl)
precip_dic <- read_excel("C:/Users/kevin/Desktop/rtrabajo.xlsx", 
                        sheet = "precip_dic")

precip_ene <- read_excel("C:/Users/kevin/Desktop/rtrabajo.xlsx", 
                         sheet = "precip_ene")

precip_feb <- read_excel("C:/Users/kevin/Desktop/rtrabajo.xlsx", 
                            sheet = "precip_feb")

rindes <- read_excel("C:/Users/kevin/Desktop/rtrabajo.xlsx", 
                     sheet = "rindess")

attach(precip_dic)
attach(precip_ene)
attach(precip_feb)
attach(rindes)

data <- cbind(precip_dic$`CORONEL SUAREZ`,precip_ene$`CORONEL SUAREZ`,precip_feb$`CORONEL SUAREZ`,rindes$`CORONEL SUAREZ`)
colnames(data) = c("dic","ene","feb","rindeas")
db <- data.frame(data)

modelo_simple <- lm(data = db,formula = rindeas ~ dic+ene+feb)
```

Comment: Me estoy riendo solo Kev, en tu primer pregunta, cuando leí 25 de mayo, 9 de Julio. lo primero que me vino a la cabeza, "que desastre, como guardan las fechas de ese modo", no pensé en las localidades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, vamos a imaginar un conjunto de datos inicial como este:

```
periodos <- paste0(1969:1995, "/", 1970:1996)
set.seed(2020)

precip_dic <- data.frame(periodo = periodos, `25 DE MAYO` = runif(27),
                         `9 DE JULIO` = runif(27), `ADOLFO ALSINA` = runif(27),
                         check.names = FALSE)

precip_ene <- data.frame(periodo = periodos, `25 DE MAYO` = runif(27),
                         `9 DE JULIO` = runif(27), `ADOLFO ALSINA` = runif(27),
                         check.names = FALSE)

precip_feb <- data.frame(periodo = periodos, `25 DE MAYO` = runif(27),
                         `9 DE JULIO` = runif(27), `ADOLFO ALSINA` = runif(27),
                         check.names = FALSE)

rindes <- data.frame(periodo = periodos, `25 DE MAYO` = runif(27),
                     `9 DE JULIO` = runif(27), `ADOLFO ALSINA` = runif(27),
                     check.names = FALSE)
```

Como puedes ver tengo 4 `data.frames` mas pequeños que los tuyos (solo 3 localidades a modo de ejemplo). La condiciones iniciales serían:

- Cada `data.frame` tiene una columna período
- Luego tiene `n` columnas por cada localidad
- Todos los datos son consistentes, cada `df` tiene la misma cantidad de observaciones y los mismos períodos
- Asumo que NO hay valores `NA`, en tu ejemplo los hay, deberás resolver este tema antes, ya que el criterio de que hacer con estos casos lo desconozco.

Habría una forma iterativa clásica de encarar el problema, pero es compleja y poco clara por lo que voy presentar una solución al estilo `tidyverse` y que hace uso del paquete
[`broom`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html) (ideal para trabajar con modelos).

En primer lugar construimos un nuevo y único `data.frame` mas "elegante" y claro para lo que vamos a hacer:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("broom")

precip_dic %>%
  gather(localidad, dic, -periodo) %>% 
  left_join(precip_ene %>%
              gather(localidad, ene, -periodo),
            by = c("periodo", "localidad")
  ) %>% 
  left_join(precip_feb %>%
            gather(localidad, feb, -periodo),
          by = c("periodo", "localidad")
  ) %>% 
  left_join(rindes %>%
              gather(localidad, rindeas, -periodo),
            by = c("periodo", "localidad")
  ) -> df

  View(df)
```

Con `gather()` llevamos las columnas de `localidad` y el valor de precipitación a filas y "juntamos" todos los meses y el rinde mediante sendos `joins`. El resultado es algo así:

```
     periodo     localidad         dic        ene        feb     rindeas
1  1969/1970    25 DE MAYO 0.646902839 0.09775849 0.49017162 0.284937043
2  1970/1971    25 DE MAYO 0.394225758 0.30675849 0.46332073 0.897857779
3  1971/1972    25 DE MAYO 0.618501814 0.39386509 0.98967034 0.232475152
4  1972/1973    25 DE MAYO 0.476891136 0.38170572 0.90022951 0.011760823
5  1973/1974    25 DE MAYO 0.136097186 0.17207094 0.57032838 0.228815810
6  1974/1975    25 DE MAYO 0.067384386 0.23390836 0.44139900 0.098551387
7  1975/1976    25 DE MAYO 0.129152617 0.36237066 0.15281970 0.336291173
8  1976/1977    25 DE MAYO 0.393117930 0.11898479 0.60669955 0.574516964
9  1977/1978    25 DE MAYO 0.002582699 0.22368575 0.98853747 0.996752853
10 1978/1979    25 DE MAYO 0.620205954 0.59989475 0.60211306 0.773867069
11 1979/1980    25 DE MAYO 0.764414018 0.77123066 0.02944212 0.632822588
12 1980/1981    25 DE MAYO 0.743835758 0.35542629 0.20486862 0.962843492
13 1981/1982    25 DE MAYO 0.826165695 0.79722178 0.86301190 0.646092761
14 1982/1983    25 DE MAYO 0.422729083 0.50884764 0.07437739 0.934257503
15 1983/1984    25 DE MAYO 0.409287665 0.18339628 0.96756603 0.428393448
16 1984/1985    25 DE MAYO 0.539692614 0.74538725 0.09888748 0.170254068
17 1985/1986    25 DE MAYO 0.960722398 0.15688116 0.69882799 0.739143074
18 1986/1987    25 DE MAYO 0.653557334 0.68750610 0.72089091 0.541186272
19 1987/1988    25 DE MAYO 0.546715299 0.42844159 0.06264259 0.267747921
20 1988/1989    25 DE MAYO 0.266063566 0.42512874 0.87850031 0.272403316
21 1989/1990    25 DE MAYO 0.196795599 0.26608799 0.02622845 0.718899705
22 1990/1991    25 DE MAYO 0.077870921 0.72619972 0.83581114 0.461124714
23 1991/1992    25 DE MAYO 0.818393328 0.93059516 0.68684126 0.424239582
24 1992/1993    25 DE MAYO 0.942404641 0.25023194 0.51675103 0.450876136
25 1993/1994    25 DE MAYO 0.884224479 0.16316596 0.89347762 0.089496193
26 1994/1995    25 DE MAYO 0.165878380 0.68298071 0.21597979 0.148085563
27 1995/1996    25 DE MAYO 0.355101338 0.78599513 0.41399763 0.062187828
28 1969/1970    9 DE JULIO 0.748095017 0.54726457 0.64134199 0.470158942
29 1970/1971    9 DE JULIO 0.450950511 0.84193869 0.21781520 0.413460688
30 1971/1972    9 DE JULIO 0.555875438 0.54824410 0.94372961 0.960807566
31 1972/1973    9 DE JULIO 0.964073088 0.02881859 0.63640823 0.873906991
32 1973/1974    9 DE JULIO 0.071468940 0.42620403 0.37545900 0.076054799
33 1974/1975    9 DE JULIO 0.955809065 0.92676956 0.75229334 0.452432964
34 1975/1976    9 DE JULIO 0.947978591 0.09204427 0.17362350 0.996118421
35 1976/1977    9 DE JULIO 0.001187752 0.40294281 0.29754955 0.826904632
36 1977/1978    9 DE JULIO 0.367279277 0.28538326 0.01635626 0.098318633
37 1978/1979    9 DE JULIO 0.011040399 0.46551464 0.24907818 0.846732790
38 1979/1980    9 DE JULIO 0.933858056 0.71864938 0.16144840 0.506024509
39 1980/1981    9 DE JULIO 0.523246557 0.51833008 0.04192389 0.682896560
40 1981/1982    9 DE JULIO 0.221986762 0.97187136 0.68940165 0.484173896
41 1982/1983    9 DE JULIO 0.985161147 0.24811167 0.16077908 0.211710899
42 1983/1984    9 DE JULIO 0.225329885 0.59899902 0.51813669 0.985790022
43 1984/1985    9 DE JULIO 0.863937630 0.83666129 0.27910392 0.853309223
44 1985/1986    9 DE JULIO 0.884683241 0.05498643 0.21471762 0.024052623
45 1986/1987    9 DE JULIO 0.624841087 0.89727322 0.64933353 0.160183328
46 1987/1988    9 DE JULIO 0.571553317 0.99931674 0.56253796 0.678556346
47 1988/1989    9 DE JULIO 0.470844345 0.68380406 0.77236707 0.595999798
48 1989/1990    9 DE JULIO 0.700667308 0.83027066 0.97011927 0.396578941
49 1990/1991    9 DE JULIO 0.797935221 0.60784825 0.17659464 0.387662719
50 1991/1992    9 DE JULIO 0.165746093 0.64380368 0.03808962 0.128038034
51 1992/1993    9 DE JULIO 0.578771094 0.51705247 0.36761516 0.990439710
52 1993/1994    9 DE JULIO 0.288274719 0.82197531 0.70821464 0.583673207
53 1994/1995    9 DE JULIO 0.902829078 0.36874717 0.93884065 0.625375883
54 1995/1996    9 DE JULIO 0.521413869 0.41858241 0.83340549 0.539600750
55 1969/1970 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.825548264 0.22355963 0.60507634 0.058942485
56 1970/1971 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.002148651 0.53703499 0.41628456 0.001118996
57 1971/1972 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.441395052 0.50060216 0.61773365 0.862094103
58 1972/1973 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.224316886 0.56681149 0.98855693 0.364244330
59 1973/1974 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.543966609 0.02875448 0.37342259 0.279486957
60 1974/1975 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.485812605 0.78693723 0.84463335 0.025789783
61 1975/1976 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.208251052 0.58743479 0.92440595 0.360883362
62 1976/1977 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.555850863 0.95011870 0.18559922 0.414463997
63 1977/1978 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.228528338 0.93607804 0.84291898 0.638507730
64 1978/1979 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.424398855 0.04299650 0.89882174 0.073641364
65 1979/1980 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.863317254 0.63007700 0.04276954 0.072555577
66 1980/1981 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.613719626 0.37511235 0.55406795 0.635115959
67 1981/1982 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.992561792 0.68161064 0.61749963 0.538179214
68 1982/1983 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.576843728 0.18296060 0.76127064 0.574640997
69 1983/1984 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.651035821 0.06537569 0.20476368 0.694404988
70 1984/1985 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.167367112 0.24071863 0.83630627 0.129691049
71 1985/1986 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.614331952 0.57525213 0.11514934 0.907627536
72 1986/1987 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.884436580 0.03769376 0.60514651 0.520118240
73 1987/1988 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.387592908 0.88279005 0.10090936 0.496892687
74 1988/1989 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.470298149 0.23506881 0.22510458 0.247398503
75 1989/1990 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.530296306 0.20484467 0.45098304 0.837802928
76 1990/1991 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.295293436 0.51840633 0.90353590 0.741524930
77 1991/1992 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.287637889 0.85822603 0.98484220 0.163458592
78 1992/1993 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.057001409 0.59625215 0.24528823 0.729189809
79 1993/1994 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.672630472 0.68102595 0.37741274 0.055410200
80 1994/1995 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.717286759 0.73510654 0.32032469 0.304095659
81 1995/1996 ADOLFO ALSINA 0.818193245 0.12562547 0.64335429 0.592033046
```

Es decir, un `df` con `periodo`, `localidad` y las 4 variables que nos importan. Ahora si vamos a generar los modelos, 1 por localidad, vamos a hacerlo del `df` original menos el último período para usar éste como dato para testear luego la predicción.

```
df %>% 
  # Quitamos el último período
  filter(periodo != "1995/1996") %>% 
  # Agrupamos por localidad
  group_by(localidad) %>% 
  # Generamos el modelo para cada localidad
  do(modelo = lm(rindeas ~ dic + ene + feb, data = .)) -> localidades_modelos

localidades_modelos

Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  localidad     modelo
* <chr>         <list>
1 25 DE MAYO    <lm>  
2 9 DE JULIO    <lm>  
3 ADOLFO ALSINA <lm>
```

Y mágicamente, tenemos una fila por localidad y una columna `modelo` de la clase `lm`, es decir el modelo lineal. Si necesitamos ahora hacer una predicción particular podríamos hacer algo tradicional como esto:

```
# Estos serán nuestros datos de testing 
df %>% 
  filter(periodo == "1995/1996") -> test

# Hacemos la prediccion para ADOLFO ALSINA
modelo <- localidades_modelos$modelo[localidades_modelos$localidad == "ADOLFO ALSINA"][[1]]
predict(modelo, test[test$localidad == "ADOLFO ALSINA",])

        3 
0.3982123
```

O bien usar [`broom`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html) y trabajar de una forma mucho más cómoda y simple:

```
test %>% 
  group_by(localidad) %>% 
  nest()  %>% 
  full_join(localidades_modelos, by = "localidad") %>% 
  do(augment(.$modelo[[1]], newdata = .$data[[1]])) 

# A tibble: 3 x 8
# Groups:   localidad [3]
  localidad     periodo     dic   ene   feb rindeas .fitted .se.fit
  <chr>         <fct>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 25 DE MAYO    1995/1996 0.355 0.786 0.414  0.0622   0.468   0.118
2 9 DE JULIO    1995/1996 0.521 0.419 0.833  0.540    0.684   0.128
3 ADOLFO ALSINA 1995/1996 0.818 0.126 0.643  0.592    0.398   0.123
```

La columna `.fitted` es el nuevo valor ajustado para cada fila. También es muy cómodo para obtener fácilmente los coeficientes de cada fila con la que construimos cada modelo por localidad:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(localidad) %>% 
  do(augment(lm(rindeas ~ dic+ene+feb, data = .)))

# A tibble: 81 x 12
# Groups:   localidad [3]
   localidad  rindeas     dic    ene   feb .fitted .se.fit .resid   .hat .sigma .cooksd .std.resid
   <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 25 DE MAYO  0.285  0.647   0.0978 0.490   0.524  0.115  -0.239 0.135   0.314 0.0264      -0.823
 2 25 DE MAYO  0.898  0.394   0.307  0.463   0.470  0.0716  0.428 0.0526  0.305 0.0275       1.41 
 3 25 DE MAYO  0.232  0.619   0.394  0.990   0.425  0.107  -0.193 0.116   0.316 0.0143      -0.658
 4 25 DE MAYO  0.0118 0.477   0.382  0.900   0.419  0.0913 -0.407 0.0857  0.306 0.0436      -1.36 
 5 25 DE MAYO  0.229  0.136   0.172  0.570   0.437  0.110  -0.209 0.125   0.316 0.0182      -0.714
 6 25 DE MAYO  0.0986 0.0674  0.234  0.441   0.437  0.115  -0.338 0.136   0.310 0.0535      -1.17 
 7 25 DE MAYO  0.336  0.129   0.362  0.153   0.466  0.118  -0.130 0.143   0.318 0.00845     -0.449
 8 25 DE MAYO  0.575  0.393   0.119  0.607   0.473  0.0985  0.101 0.0995  0.318 0.00323      0.342
 9 25 DE MAYO  0.997  0.00258 0.224  0.989   0.362  0.153   0.634 0.239   0.279 0.426        2.33 
10 25 DE MAYO  0.774  0.620   0.600  0.602   0.450  0.0782  0.324 0.0628  0.311 0.0193       1.07 
# ... with 71 more rows
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio ha sido de gran ayuda tu respuesta, existe la posibilidad de obtener un data frame con los coeficientes de cada regresión y los valores de los R cuadrado

Comment: Hola @kev, revisa las funciones del paquete `broom`, `tidy` y `glance` la primera creo que te da los coeficientes y la segunda los r cuadrados.