# Calculos en un panel data en r

Tags: r, rstudio

tengo un dataset con la siguiente estructura

```
         year     var      cod                   localidad
34    1999-12-01  82.5      S1                   9 de Julio
35    1999-12-11  64.4      S1                   9 de Julio
36    1999-12-21  58.4      S1                   9 de Julio
37    2000-01-01  43.0      S1                   9 de Julio
38    2000-01-11  43.5      S1                   9 de Julio
39    2000-01-21  20.8      S1                   9 de Julio
40    2000-02-01  24.5      S1                   9 de Julio
41    2000-02-11  50.0      S1                   9 de Julio
42    2000-02-21  51.6      S1                   9 de Julio
43    2000-03-01  52.5      S1                   9 de Julio
44    2000-03-11  52.4      S1                   9 de Julio
45    2000-03-21  74.7      S1                   9 de Julio
```

Tengo para un mismo **year** dos valores de **var**, uno correspondiente a S1 y otro a S2 de la variable **cod**. Necesito calcular la media de **var** entre los dos valores de **cod** para todas las observaciones. ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con `dplyr/tidyverse` puedes hacer:

```
library("dplyr")
df %>% 
  group_by(year, localidad) %>%
  summarize(media = mean(var))
```

Agrupamos el `data.frame` por localidad y año, y sumarizamos en la nueva columna `media` el valor del media de `var`. En R base, algo similar podría ser: `aggregate(var ~ ., df, mean)`.

Comment: Me parece que en este caso no es escrictamente necesario incluir `localidad` dentro de `group_by()`. No sabemos con certeza si `localidad` es una constante.

Comment: @SamuelCalderon, es cierto lo que dices, seguramente es un "asumido" personal, productode  que ya he respondido algo al respecto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329202/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-muchas-regresiones-en-r, De todas formas, es bueno aclararlo.